# onmouseover show DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, mouseover, shadowbox

Have you done search on google recently?
After google displays the search, if you put your mouse over search term google displays a preview of the site to the right with shadowbox and allows the user to control (close) the DIV.

How do I achieve that script?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it would help to have Google's resources...

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/8/unledxvc.jpg/   but with shadowbox around it and the popup below the mouse not to the right. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many steps required in getting you to that point.

First, check out [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and become comfortable with the syntax.

Second, read up on the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function which will allow you to do something like this:

```
$('#my_preview_link').hover(function(){
    $('#my_preview_div').fadeIn();
},function(){
    $('#my_preview_div').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

http://api.jquery.com/hover/